# Spotify web player have issues with connecting

Tags: connection, load, spotify

I have searched quite some for an answer to my question, haven't found one, quite new though so sorry in advance if anything is out of order.

I've been experiencing some issues with the web player embeded iframe. 
Sometimes it get stuck at loading, at first it worked great, but now it completly loads every third time, ish.
Worked better but still some issues in Safari and Firefox (running om mac).

//Html

```
<?php getSelectedPlaylist($db); ?>
<?php if(checkStatus()===true): ?>

<div id="comment-container">
<form method="POST"> 
<textarea name="comment" cols="80" rows="5" > </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Posta kommentar"> </input>
</form> 
<?php endif;?>



<div class="comment-result">
<?php setCommentsPlaylist($db); ?>
</div> <!-- comment-result -->
<?php getCommentsPlaylist($db);?>
</div> <!-- comment-container -->





// php 
foreach ($result as $key){
$key["Users_userid"];
echo '<div class="info-container"><p> Namn: ';
echo $key["name"];
echo '</p>';
echo 'Delad av användaren: '.$username[0]["Username"];
echo '<p> Genre : ';
echo $key["genre"]."</p></div>";
echo '<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri='.$key["uri"].'" width="400" height="900" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>';
voteButtonSong($db,$key["songId"]);

}
```

I am not using any authentication codes, just the web player itself, and a get-function for a uri in my database.

:EDIT Seems like the javascript isn't kicking in, here is a image:

[Iframe when it isn't loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXcZa.png)

EDIT 2 :

Seems like it is waiting for analytics.twitter.com, saw it in the bottom left corner in chrome.
Thanks in advance